# OSX app to notify me when I could have used a KB shortcut instead?

Tags: macos, finder, productivity, keybindings

I started using a MBA for my work machine about a year ago. I'm still not really able to remember the typical keyboard shortcuts, and tend to do things the "long way". For example, if I want to access the Desktop within Finder I'll tend to click on the Finder icon in my Dock, then navigate to Desktop within that window. Then kick myself because I could have just hit SHIFT CMD D.

So is anyone aware of any small apps which notice this happen and simply notify me something like "by the way, you could do this far quicker by using this keyboard shortcut: SHIFT CMD D".

The question's inspired by a plugin called Keyboard Promoter that I use in PHPStorm, my IDE of choice: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4455?pr=phpStorm. I'd like something similar system-wide, not just within the IDE.

Comment: I, sadly, don't have an answer for you. But I thought I'd drop a note anyway, because this is one of the best ideas I've seen in ages.